# Replicasets are not creating in mongodb community operator

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-operator, mongodb-cluster

I am creating mongodb cluster using following documentation.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/blob/master/docs/deploy-configure.md

I am trying to create custom resources as following.

```sh
kubectl apply -f config/samples/mongodb.com_v1_mongodbcommunity_cr.yaml
```

It is saying created successfully but I am unable to see any replicaset created for that and also no pods are being created for the same. I am using minikube to generate resources.

Comment: What do you get when you execute `kubectl get pods` and `kubectl get rs` ? Please update your question with the output of these commands.

Comment: that's what I had checked for pods. pods were not getting created for them so nothing was showing related to those pods and rs. But got the fix now as I didn't know we can also check logs for custom kind. so. I have posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue as I came to know how can we check logs of custom "kind" in Kubernetes.

As I checked mongodbcommunity kind as follows. And it was giving failed stage.

```
kubectl get mongodbcommunity
```

Then I checked the following command for mongodbcommunity.

```
kubectl describe mongodbcommunity
```

It was showing errors as secrets are not found. I had changed credentials in custom resources but didn't update in secrets. So it was failing.

In the dashboard, nothing was happening and even during executing yaml no errors were showing up and were showing as "created".

So I just didn't know how to check the issue for this but figured way and after correcting the username properly MongoDB cluster is working fine now.